# How is `(d*a)mod(b)=1` written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

How should I write this:

```
(d*a)mod(b)=1
```

in order to make it work properly in Ruby? I tried it on Wolfram, but their solution:

```
(da(b, d))/(dd) = -a/d
```

doesn't help me. I know `a` and `b`. I need to solve `(d*a)mod(b)=1` for `d` in the form `d=...`.

Comment: are you looking for [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)?

Comment: yes, but I know a and b and I searching d, and can't transform (d*a)mod(b)=1 to d = ...

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking, and, depending on what you mean, a solution may be impossible.

First off, `(da(b, d))/(dd) = -a/d`, is not a solution to that equation; rather, it's a misinterpretation of the notation used for partial derivatives. What Wolfram Alpha actually gave you was:
[image: formula], which is entirely unrelated.

Secondly, if you're trying to solve `(d*a)mod(b)=1` for `d`, you may be out of luck. For any value of `a` and `b`, where `a` and `b` have a common prime factor, there are an infinite number of values of `d` that satisfy the equation. If `a` and `b` are coprime, you can use the formula given in LutzL's answer.

Additionally, if you're looking to perform symbolic manipulation of equations, Ruby is likely not the proper tool. Consider using a CAS, like Python's SymPy or Wolfram Mathematica.

Finally, if you're just trying to compute `(d*a)mod(b)`, the modulo operator in Ruby is `%`, so you'd write `(d*a)%(b)`.

Comment: I dont want to calculate (d*a)%(b) i need to solve it for d, but https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%20a(b%2C%20d)%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20d%7D%3D%20-%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bd%7D   can't be pasted in ruby and when you click to show you code wolfram returns (da(b, d))/(dd) = -a/d

Comment: @SimeonShopkin Per Wikipedia, "∂ is a stylized d mainly used as a mathematical symbol to denote a partial derivative." Notice what Wolfram Alpha is displaying when you click to show code; the section you're clicking on is entitled "Implicit Derivatives." This is not what you want. If you need to solve for `d`, and `a` and `b` are coprime, use LutzL's answer. Otherwise, what you're asking is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [**modular inverse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of a modulo b.

---

For any two numbers a,b the [extended euclidean](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) algorithm

```
g,u,v = xgcd(a, b)
```

gives coefficients u,v such that

```
u*a+v*b = g
```

and g is the greatest common divisor. You need a,b co-prime, preferably by ensuring that b is a prime number, to get g=1 and then you can set d=u.

---

```
xgcd(a,b)
    if b = 0
        return (a,1,0)
    q,r = a divmod b 
    // a = q*b + r
    g,u,v = xgcd(b, r) 
    // g = u*b + v*r = u*b + v*(a-q*b) = v*a+(u-q*v)*b
    return g,v,u - q*v
```